# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, mysql, ssh

Подключаюсь через SSH к MySQL

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SSHHost" value="79.173.x.y"/>
  <add key="SSHUser" value="xyz"/>
  <add key="SSHPassword" value="xyz"/>
  <add key="SSHPort" value="22"/>
  <add key="SQLHost" value="79.173.x.y"/>
  <add key="SQLIPA" value="127.0.0.1"/>
  <add key="SQLPort" value="1500"/>
  <add key="SQLConnectionString" value="Server=127.0.0.1; Port=3306; Database=test; Uid=xyz; Pass="/>
  <add key="SQLSelect" value="select * from test"/>
</appSettings>
```

На локальном компьютере все хорошо (странно, если бы было иначе, на других уже все плохо). Что я делаю не так?

```
PasswordConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new PasswordConnectionInfo(Const.Host, Const.Port, Const.User, Const.Password);
        connectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        using(var client = new SshClient(connectionInfo))
        {
            try
            {
                client.Connect();
                if(client.IsConnected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SSH connection is active");

                } else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SSH connection failed");
                }
                var portFwdl = new ForwardedPortLocal(Const.SQLIPA, Const.SQLPort, Const.SQLHost, Const.SQLPort);
                client.AddForwardedPort(portFwdl);
                portFwdl.Start();
                if(portFwdl.IsStarted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("PORT forwarding is started");
                } else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("PORT forwarding faile");
                }
                string strConnection = Const.SQLConn;
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);
                string myTablename = "test";
                MySqlDataAdapter myDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                myDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(Const.SQLSELECT, conn);
                MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myDA);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("SQL connection is active");
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet("id");                       
                    myDA.Fill(ds, myTablename);                        
                    Console.WriteLine(ds.GetXml());                        
                }
                catch(MySqlException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
                client.Disconnect();
                Console.WriteLine("SHH Disconnect");

            } catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше приводить в виде текста, а не картинки: во-первых, читать удобнее, во-вторых, текст, в отличие от картинки, индексируется и может быть найден и с помощью поисковых систем, и внутри-сайтовым и внутри-браузерным поиском.

Comment: Индексировать IP адрес? Зачем? Заголовок вопроса и так хорошо проиндексируется

Comment: индексировать **текст**. ip-адрес и прочую непубличную информацию можно удалить либо (лучше) заменить «рыбой». // что появляется в логах mysqld после неудачной попытки подключения?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin где это посмотреть?

Comment: в логах *mysqld*. где эти логи — указано в конфигурации *mysqld*. обычно — в районе `/var/log/...`

Comment: да и от самой вашей программы неплохо бы получить *внятную* информацию о проблемах, с которыми она «столкнулась».

Comment: Я если честно не понимаю о каких логах идет речь, mysql на сервере ничего не оставляла последние сутки, а моя программа по подключению к БД точно ничего не оставляет кроме как сообщений в консоли. Проблема в том, что я пытаюсь присоединиться к MySQL на своем сервере через SSH с пробросом портов. Я до этого этим не занимался, поэтому мне это не понятно. На компьютере, где расположена БД, я получаю результаты, на других компьютерах в сети (а и вне сети подавно) я ничего не получаю. Никаких данных, только ошибка, которая в заголовке вопроса.

Comment: программа написана не вами? у вас есть от неё исходники?

Comment: Есть, куда мне их прикрепить?

Answer (score 1):

**предуведомление**: изложенное ниже — лишь гипотеза, т.к. никакой диагностической информации предоставлено не было.

---

> ForwardedPortLocal

судя по названию этой функции, вероятно, логика вашей программы заключается не в запуксе программы-*mysql*-клиента на удалённом компьютере, а в т.н. «пробросе портов» (port forwarding).

поэтому подключение (с точки зрения *mysqld*) происходит не с локального (для него) компьютера, а с удалённого.

соответственно, учётная запись `plzvtl@localhost` (где `plzvtl` — имя *mysql*-пользователя, под именем которого вы пытаетесь подключиться к *mysqld*) в таблице `user` базы данных `mysql` (это «служебная» база данных) — не подходит. т.к. для *mysqld* ваше подключение выглядит как подключение от пользователя `plzvtl@ваш.внешний.ip.адрес.или.имя.домена`.

можно, конечно, добавить (или исправить существующую) запись в таблицу `user` с именно таким логином. но это не универсально (вы не сможете подключиться с другого компьютера, имеющего другое «внешнее» имя и/или ip-адрес).

я бы предложил указать для данного пользователя возможность подключаться с *любого* ip-адреса: `plzvtl@%`.

для этого (один из возможных вариантов) подключитесь к *mysqld* на сервере, используя логин и пароль пользователя, имеющего достаточные полномочия для внесения изменений в базу данных `mysql` (скорее всего, это пользователь *root*):

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

и в интерактивном режиме введите команды:

```
> use mysql;
> update user set host='%' where user='plzvtl';
> flush privileges;
```

Comment: Не, не работает. Дело в том, что я без SSH могу подключаться, указывая в connString прямой адрес, но через тоннелирование с указанием в connString 127.0.0.1 или localhost получаю Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. Авторизовыаться можно с любого ip.